What does よし mean in senryuu?
I am uncertain about the meaning of よし in this senryuu:

I could be wrong but I think this よし is just 良し. The senryuu reads "About this dandelion, the flower is nice, the stem is nice, the smell is also nice." Is that correct?

... I don't see よし anywhere on the image?

@KarlKnechtel The し curves so slightly it might look like a vertical stroke to you. There's a し after each よ in the image (x3 total).

Yes, it's just 良し. Your translation is good but I'd change it to "Dandelions (in general)":
Dandelions
the flower is good, the stem is good
and they smell nice.

